# Looking for dynamic programming solution

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, spell-checking, dynamic-programming

I have the following problem:

A string (with no blank spaces in it) is given. And I also have a cost function that returns the cost of the string (built by adding the evaluated cost of each word in the string). Actually it uses a dictionary and evaluates the edit distance.

My program needs to insert spaces (as few as possible) to obtain the optimum global cost.

I want the raw algorithm, optimizations will come further.

**Example:**

errorfreesampletext -> error free sample text
scchawesomeness -> such awesomeness

Comment: Okay, what did you try doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work.

```
dp[i] = minimum cost if we consider only the first i characters

for i = 1 to n do
  dp[i] = cost(a[1, i]) // take sequence [1, i] without splitting it
  for k = 1 to i - 1 do
    dp[i] = min(dp[i], dp[k] + cost(a[k + 1, i])) // see if it's worth splitting 
                                                  // sequence [1, i] into
                                                  // [1, k] and [k + 1, i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm. It is probably not the most efficient, but is the best one I could think of.

```
Input:
   A string of length n
   A list of words
Create a lookup table:
   Create a grid M of n x n slots. (1..n, 1..n)
   Create a grid W of n x n slots. (1..n, 1..n)
   For each starting position i in 1..n:
      For each ending position j in i..n:
         For each word w:
            Find the edit distance d between w and substring (i..j)
            If d is less than M[i,j]:
               Set M[i,j] to d
               Set W[i,j] to w
Find the best words for each position:
   Create a list L of (n+1) slots. (0..n)
   Create a list C of (n+1) slots. (0..n)
   Set L[0] to 0
   For each ending position i in 1..n:
      Set L[i] to infinity
      For each starting position j in 0..i-1:
         If L[j] + M[i,j] is less than L[i]:
            Set L[i] to L[j] + M[i,j]
            Set C[i] to j
Create the final result string:
   Create a list R
   Let i be the length of the input (n)
   Repeat while i > 0:
      Let j be C[i]
      Prepend W[j,i] to R
      Set i to j-1
   Return R
```

This algorithm is split in three stages:

1. The first stage calculates a lookup-table. *M* is the best cost of fitting any word into substring *i*..*j*. *W* is the word associated with that cost. *O*(*n*<sup>3</sup> *m w*) (*n* = input length, *w* = maximum word length, and *m* = word count)
2. The second stage finds the best words for each position. *L* is the best total cost up to position *i*. *C* is the starting position of the last word associated with that cost. *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>)
3. The last stage assembles the final string. *R* is a list of words that receives the least cost when matched against the input string. *O*(*n*).

The first stage is the most costly. It should probably be possible to shave off an order of magnitude from it, but I don't see how. You could also combine it with stage 2, but you wouldn't gain much from it.